# Lisp membership node in a tree

Tags: tree, lisp, common-lisp

I need a function that tests the membership of a node in an N-tree represented as `(root list_of_nodes_subtree1 ... list_of_nodes_subtreen)`. For example, if the tree is `(a (b (c)) (d) (e (f)))` and the node is `b`, then we expect a true value.

I tried some map functions but I can't figure this out. I'm fairly new to lisp.Some explanation would mean the world to me.

Comment: Do you have a more specific example on which we could work? And what have you tried exaclty? Your tree is made up how and from what (struct, class, nested list, hash-tables...)?

Comment: (A (B) (C (D) (E))).Is made from nested list.

Comment: (defun check (L X)
  (cond 
    ((equal X L) T)
    (t (list(apply #'append
              (mapcar #'check L)
             )
       )
      )
    )
  )
(A (B) (C (D) (E))).Is made from nested list.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
(defun check (element tree &key (test #'eq))
  "The tree is simply a nested list."
  (cond
   ;; If the tree is empty
   ((null tree)
    nil)
   ;; If the tree is a list
   ((listp tree)
    (or
     ;; Recurse on the head of the list.
     (check element (car tree) :test test)
     ;; Recurse on the tail of the list.
     (check element (cdr tree) :test test)))
   ;; If the tree is just a node
   (t
    (funcall test element tree))))

;; Testing
(loop for el in '(a b c d e f g) collect
  (check el '(a (b) (c (d) (e)))))
```

Note that I used `eq` by default instead of `equal` because we were comparing symbols of the same package, but you can use any comparaison funcion you want.

Comment: You can use `(trace check)` to see what is happening :D

Comment: The usual default test is `eql`.